# What is returned? (Class method access on instantiation)

Tags: php

### EDIT: Please note that I am appending my original question with my actual question due to realizing that I asked the wrong question (by forgetting what I actually meant to ask).

In PHP 5.4 (as of RC1), it is possible to access class methods on class instantiation.

In other words, as I understand it, it is now possible to do: `$foo = new bar()->foobar();` which saves times and lines of code.

For my question, let's look at the following example:

```
class foo {
    function __construct() {
    }

    function bar() {
        return 'world';
    }
}

$foobar = (new foo())->bar();
echo $foobar;
```

My question is, in such a case, when both the constructor and the method that is called upon initialization return a value, what is output by the final line (i.e. `echo $foobar;`)?

If I had to guess, since I haven't actually had a chance to play around with 5.4 yet, the return from foo::bar() would overwrite the return from foo::__construct() because it is returned last. But I just wanted to check.

---

Okay, so the above question is not even logical (since __construct() should not return). What I really meant to ask is this:
Does $foobar in the above example contain the class instance or the return from $bar? If the latter, what sense does it make to use this if the class will not be available after instantiated? Wouldn't it be better to just use a static method or call the method on its own line?

Comment: Does it really make sense to return something on your constructor?

Comment: For the record, I asked the wrong question. I actually meant to ask: Does $foobar contain the class instance or the value of bar()? And in the latter case, what sense does it make to use this if you cannot then access the class instance?

Comment: @imkingdavid: `bar()` *can* access the class instance.

Comment: @hakre: yes, it can, but $foobar cannot. So basically you're create an entire new instance just to run one method. It would make more sense to me to use a static method instead, since otherwise you lose access to that instance of the class (after bar() is run)

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Fair enough, but I cannot think of any case in which I would instantiate a class just to access one method's return value.

Comment: `$foobar = ($foo = new foo())->bar();` -- just express what you want.

Comment: @imkingdavid i know, you rarely do that actually. Normaly speaking, you'd use a static method, but in some cases it's useful to do so for many other architectural reasons...

Comment: @hakre I had just thought about this cause i've done it once in c#, so i guess it would be possible in PHP...

Comment: @hakre ahh, I didn't realize you could do that. That's handy.
MathieuDumoulin: alright, thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not just try these things out and see for yourself? You'll learn much more by experimenting and discovering than just asking to be spoon fed information. -1

Comment: @vascowhite: current I don't have PHP 5.4 installed. I'm waiting until it's actually released before I go through the trouble. I don't mind not getting an answer when I post such a question on here (since I probably will eventually try it myself), but I figure I'll ask and if someone who already knows the answer can help, it'll save time. I'm not going to download an RC version of PHP just to check on the behavior of one new feature. Plus, I wouldn't learn other cool new things like in hakre's second comment. ;)

Comment: Point taken, but I still think you'd learn more by downloading the RC and experimenting :)

Comment: @imkingdavid: Try your code in PHP 5.4 here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/sFDKfG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never return anything from a constructor. Thats a basic rule. Now some of us don't follow this because they like the concept of calling their constructor afterwards and receiving some input instead of nothing.

But in the case of a good programming strategy, a constructor should be called only via the "new" keyword and shouldn't return anything.

And yes, in all cases, NEW CLASSNAME() returns the instanciated object in all cases :)

Happy programming...

```
<?php
class myclass {
        public function __construct(){
                return 'hello';
        }
}

$a = new myclass();
var_dump($a);
var_dump($a->__construct());
```

Will output

```
object(myclass)#1 (0) { } 
string(5) "hello"
```

**EDIT following question change**

My educated guess is that $foobar will contain "world" and thus echo it with your code.

Same thing occurs in other languages such as in c#. You can instanciate an object call a method directly inline and lose the object only to get the return from the inline function called.

```
var_dump(new foo()); //Will var_dump the object
var_dump(new foo()->bar()); //Will var_dump "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing parenthesis:

```
$foobar = (new foo())->bar();
echo $foobar; # world
```

Because `__construct()` returns nothing, the `return` statement is useless inside the constructor. That was possible in PHP 4 IIRC, but since PHP 5 `new` will always return the object.

**Edit:**

> Does `$foobar` in the above example contain the class instance or the return from $[sic!]bar[()]?

The return value (if you fix the parenthesis). So the latter.

> If the latter, what sense does it make to use this if the class will not be available after instantiated?

What makes sense or not is in the eye of the beholder. Normally you can not look into classes, so, expect that a class method needs the object.

> Wouldn't it be better to just use a static method or call the method on its own line?

Calling a static function is not the same as calling an object method. For example, the method might not work when called statically.

Writing the method call on it's own line is generally considered good practice because it's better readable:

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->bar();
```